# p-series type power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Are there any results/papers/books for series of the type
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^p},\quad p \in \mathbb{R}\quad\text{?}$$
There are the special cases $p = 0$, $p=1$, which are well known. I would be interested especially in the cases $0 < p < 1$, in particular $p = 1/2$.

Comment: [Polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), especially $\newcommand{plog}{\operatorname{Li}}\plog_{1/2}(x)$.

Comment: Polylogarithm section in http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polylogarithm $Li(1/2,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^{1/2}}$ has a radius of convergence of $\vert x\vert<1, x\neq-1$ following from the geometric series convergence criteria and the fact that $Li(1/2,1)=\zeta(1/2)$ which is divergent. Interestingly, for $Li(1/2,-1)$, the sum is equal to $-\eta(1/2)$ which is convergent.

Comment: $\plog_{1/2}(1)\ne\zeta(1/2)$. $\zeta(1/2)$ is finite, and $\plog_{1/2}(1)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: How is $Li(1/2,1)\neq\zeta(1/2)$? And using the traditional zeta definition, doesn't $\zeta(s)$ only converge for $\Re(s)>1$?

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ usually refers to the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^s}$, which is defined everywhere except $c=1$.

Comment: Also $\text{Li}_s(z)$ is entire in $s$ and continuous in $z, |z| \le 1, z \ne 1$